# How do I change a MERGEFIELD into a Handlebar

Tags: handlebars.js

So I am not a coding pro but I need to change the following expression using handlebars LOL I don't even know if this is the correct wording. Here goes nothing LOL

{IF {MERGEFIELD Tribute} = "" "" "{MERGEFIELD Tribute} "} {IF {MERGEFIELD FamilyName} = "" "" " An acknowledgement of your donation has been sent to {MERGEFIELD FamilyName} " }

Comment: I don't know how to help you because I don't know what all of this "MERGEFIELD" stuff means. I suspect you are using some kind of emailing service that leverages Handlebars templates. Perhaps there are some additional tags that are specific to the service you are using that could be added to increase the likelihood of your post getting seen by the right eyes.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.